# Pass value whether its negative or positive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble passing the value to a specific `input`. I put `var` to detect but seems it doesn't work.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#cash_advance").on("keydown keyup", sum);

  function sum() {
    $("#total").val(Number($("#cash_advance").val()) - Number($("#sum").val()));
  }

  var num = $("#total").val();
  var to_refunded = $("#to_refunded");
  var to_reimbursed = $("#to_reimbursed");

  if (num < 0) {
    to_refunded.val(num);
  } else if (num > 0) {
    to_reimbursed.val(num);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question php?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi oh im also a php language

Comment: Right, but the question has nothing to do with that. I've re-tagged it for you. Also note that it would help to see your HTML so we can have a working example of the issue

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh okay. thank you. i though you have to tag what language currently using for this one

Comment: That's right, you do. But the problem in the question has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

The code that uses `num` needs to be in the event handler function. Otherwise it just runs once, when the page first loads, not when the user edits the input field.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#cash_advance").on("keydown keyup", sum);

  function sum() {
    var num = Number($("#cash_advance").val()) - Number($("#sum").val());
    $("#total").val(num);
    var to_refunded = $("#to_refunded");
    var to_reimbursed = $("#to_reimbursed");

    if (num < 0) {
      to_refunded.val(num);
    } else if (num > 0) {
      to_reimbursed.val(num);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: oh i get it! you use the num to name the difference of the 2 values. thank you so much!